# How to modify Symfony ORM insert\update query

Tags: symfony, orm

I have project that is migrate to Symfony, that project have multiple tables,and also some tables are migrated to ORM, but now i need to incert/update from Symfony to table that have Entity but not managed by ORM. Problem consist in not null columns that require some value and in Entity I cannot define that value because of table relations.

It posible to edit MySql query before they submited to Database.

For example i have Entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="p_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=55, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var Permission
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Permission", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="permission_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $permission;
}
```

`permission_id` can be null but in database is not null with default value 0, same for `name` but with default value ''.

That mean when I make `flush`, ORM execute `INSERT INTO p_user (name, permission_id) VALUES ('name', null)`, but I want also to execute `INSERT INTO p_user (name) VALUES ('name')`.

It's possible to do that I wanted.

Comment: It is impractical to adjust Doctrine generated insert/update sql code.  Just use: private $permission = 0; to set a default value.

Comment: If you've a solution please use the answer section instead of add it inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can provide default values.

```
private $permission = 0;

private $name = '';
```

Comment: don't know why but this dont work, its set null and not value defined

Comment: i fond solution to create custom nulltype but now my problem is with ManyToOne, OneToOne, OneToMany relations